# How to calculate $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^n\left( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right)^n $?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\sqrt n} \left( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right)^n
$$

How is this limit? And how does it work?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Calculate the limit of the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $1-1/\sqrt n > 1/2$ for $n>4.$ For such $n$ the expression is at least $e^n\cdot (1/2)^n = (e/2)^n \to \infty.$

Comment: Nice and elementary.

Answer (score 4):

The logarithm of the expression is
$$n+n\ln\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt n}\right).$$
Recall that
$$\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$$
for $x\to0$ etc.

Comment: Note that if you go off the question that was in the title with $e^{\sqrt n}$ instead of $e^n$ you get $$ \sqrt n + n \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right) = \sqrt n - \sqrt n - \frac{1}{2} \frac{n}{(\sqrt{n})^2} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{n} {(\sqrt{n})^3} + O(n^{-1}) \to -\frac12$$ so that limit is $e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0 < c < 1$,
let
$f(n)
=e^n \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^{1-c}} \right)^n
$.

Then,
using
$\ln(1-x) = -x+O(x^2)$
for small $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(f(n))
&=n+n\ln(1-\frac{1}{n^{1-c}})\\
&=n+n(-\frac{1}{n^{1-c}}+O(\frac{1}{n^{2-2c}}))\\
&=n-n^c+O(\frac{1}{n^{1-2c}})\\
\end{array}
$

Since $c < 1$,
$n^c = o(n)$
so
$n-n^c
\to \infty$.

If $c > \frac12$,
$\frac{1}{n^{1-2c}}
=n^{2c-1}
=o(n)
$
since
$2c-1 < 1$.

Therefore
$\ln(f(n))
= n-o(n)
\to \infty$
so
$f(n) \to infty$.

Your question is the case
$c = \frac12$.